# Understanding the use-case of a Powershell global variable

Tags: wpf, powershell, global-variables

Recently, I've been working on a project where I try to create GUIs for my Powershell scripts. Even though, there seems to exists a lot of possibilities, I found one way to do it designed by a Microsoft PFE: *Chris Conte*.

If you guys are interested you can find the article [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/08/01/ive-got-a-powershell-secret-adding-a-gui-to-scripts/).

Now, my question is related particularly to the `loadDialog.ps1` script, which is basically the link between a XAML form and your original Powershell script. Here is the code:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
  [string]$XamlPath
)

[xml]$Global:xmlWPF = Get-Content -Path $XamlPath

#Add WPF and Windows Forms assemblies
try{
    Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework,WindowsBase,system.windows.forms
} catch {
    Throw "Failed to load Windows Presentation Framework assemblies."
}

#Create the XAML reader using a new XML node reader
$Global:xamGUI = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load((new-object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xmlWPF))

#Create hooks to each named object in the XAML
$xmlWPF.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | %{
    Set-Variable -Name ($_.Name) -Value $xamGUI.FindName($_.Name) -Scope Global
    }
```

Since `$xamGUI` and newly created variables captured by the XAML reader are shared between scripts I can understand their global scope. My question is specific to this line:

> `[xml]$Global:xmlWPF = Get-Content -Path $XamlPath`

Why is he using a global scope ? Is this in case we would want to use it somewhere else or there is something I'm missing? I'm still new to Powershell environnement and the snippet's author clearly has notoriety in the Powershell world, so I'm guessing there is a reason for this declaration but I can't get what this is.

Comment: By definition the only time that GLOBAL scope is needed is if you want to access variables in multiple separate scripts.

Comment: The global scope on the WPF template variable is unnecessary and likely a slip-up unless he's utilizing that variable in another script.

Comment: Just as a warning, I'd put the time to learning enough `C#`to develop an actual GUI with WPF rather than shoe-horning GUIs into PowerShell scripts (for anything but a single-layer GUI)

Comment: @EBGreen Thank you for your answer, I hate using unnecessary global variables this is why I was wondering. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I know this is not the particular topic, but could you elaborate a bit on this. Because my first idea was to use C#/WPF for GUIs, I'm already familiar with C#. The problem is, I don't understand the workflow. Where would I call the powershell script ? from within the C# code ?

Comment: Don't call powershell at all. Just do everything in C#.

Comment: Yea, that would imply for me to re-write every script tho.

Comment: Yes, you can call your PowerShell scripts from C# code. It's another topic though. Gist: `PowerShell.Create().AddScript(...).Invoke()`.

Comment: @scharette You would call the scripts inside event handlers for the GUI actions.  There are nice PowerShell classes you can utilize inside C#

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 Would I increase performance by utilizing C# ? Or is there other adavantages ?

Comment: Author of script thinks that it might be useful to access this variable by users of the script, there is nothing more to that. For example, one might need to find some object in this xml which is not identified by `Name`. Since it's general-purpose script - there is nothing wrong to provide global variable for potential future use.

Comment: @Evk thanks for your answer. Appreciated!

Comment: Yes, performance advantages, maintainable project advantages, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The helper script is essentially "returning" things - the XML, form and all the controls - to the user as variables. For example, if there was a button labelled `button1` in the XAML, the script would create a global variable `$global:button1`. You can then use this variable to attach an event handler:

`$button1.add_Click{ $Label1.Content = "Hello World" }`
 
It's in the event handler where the need for these global variables becomes obvious. You somehow have to pass the form controls to the event handler scriptblock - in this case, `Label1`. The simplest way to do this is to create the variables in a parent (e.g. global) scope and allow dynamic scoping to do the work for you.  C# uses a similar (but lexically scoped) approach by making all of the controls members of the enclosing class.

Comment: As I said, _Since $xamGUI and newly created variables captured by the XAML reader are shared between scripts I can understand their global scope_. I understand what the script does, my question is concerning `$xmlWPF`.